# Show that the case $A$ is true

Tags: logic

Let $A,B,C$ three logical cases. Assuming that $B$ is false and $C$ is true. Assuming that we have the following implications:

$C⇒A$

$C⇒B$

$C⇒A$ or $B$

Then show that the case $A$ is true.

Comment: How can we have $C\implies B$ if $C$ is true and $B$ is false?

Comment: @Arthur: we want to deduce that $A$ is true.

Comment: @Safwane but it does not make sense to have simultaneously $B$ false, $C$ true and the property $C\implies B$.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso: Yes. But the implications are the results of some proofs and assumptions. So, the conclusion is to prove that $A$ is true.

Comment: @Safwane Oh, I see. Have you seen the answer I posted? I hope that's what you were expecting.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso: Yes. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Safwane your welcome! Comment the answer if there's anything you don't undersand.

Answer (score 1):

First, it does not make sense for $C$ to be true and $B$ false, since you have said that the property
$$C\implies B$$
is true.

Then, since $C\implies A$, we got that
$$C \text{ true} \implies A \text{ true},$$
and you said $C$ is true so we conclude $A$ is also true.

We can also deduce the same from the property $C\implies A \vee B$, since we are assuming $B$ is false, so in order for $A \vee B$ to be true, then $A$ must be true.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, no proof of $A$ being true is possible, because as others have pointed out, the premises are **contradictory**.

When you have contradictory premises, no implications can be meaningful.

For example, suppose that you have two premises: 
[1] $P$ 
[2] $\neg P.$

Suppose that $Q$ is any other assertion.

Then, from [1], you have $(P \vee Q).$

Then, you have, (from the previous result + [2]), 
that $Q$ must be true.

You can similarly prove that $\neg Q$ must also be true.

Clearly the situation becomes **nonsensical**.

Comment: When the premises contain a contradiction, then it is valid to conclude anything.  This is the Principle of Explosion; also known as *ex falso quodlibet*.$$\bot\vdash A$$